# Trouble replicating hero transition from demo

Tags: polymer

I'm fairly new at this and have been trying to learn through examples and demos.

I am trying to get a handle on the core animated pages but the concepts seem to have eluded me.

Here are my attempts with plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/rHUrUEhpprTUEUJ7JrBh?p=preview

```html
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-shadow/paper-shadow.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-icon-button/core-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-animated-pages/core-animated-pages.html">
  <polymer-element name="test-element">
  <template>

    <style>
 paper-shadow {
   block: inline-block;
  width: 360px;
  max-height: 600px;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 16px;
 }
 .upper {
   
 }
 .mid img {
   width: 360px;
   max-height: 360px;
 }
    </style>

    <core-animated-pages selected="{{page}}" transitions="hero-transition" on-core-animated-pages-transition-end="{{complete}}">

  <section>
  
    <template repeat="{{cards as card}}">
    
  <paper-shadow>
  <section class="upper" horizontal layout hero-id="hero1" hero?="{{selectedCard === item}}">
    <h1>{{card.creator}}</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="mid" hero-id="hero2" hero?="{{selectedCard === card}}">
    <img src="{{card.image}}">
  </section>
  <section class="bottom">
    <h1>{{card.title}}</h1>
  </section>
  
  </paper-shadow>
  
  </template>
  
  </section>
  
  
  <section id="trans-card">
    <div class="dialog" layout horizontal hero-id="hero1" hero on-tap="{{transition}}">
      <div class="dialog-left" style="background:{{selectedCard.image}};" hero-id="hero2" hero></div>
      <div class="dialog-right" flex>
        <div layout horizontal center>
          <div>
            <div class="dialog-icon" style="background: #f4dv33;"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="dialog-title">{{selectedCard.creator}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


    </core-animated-pages>

  </template>
  
  <script>

    Polymer('test-element', {

      page: 0,
      
      cards: [
        { title: 'Test Title 1', image: 'http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg', creator: 'random guy1'},
        { title: 'Test Title 2', image: 'http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg', creator: 'random guy2'},
        { title: 'Test Title 3', image: 'http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg', creator: 'random guy3'}
        ],


      selectedCard: null,

      transition: function(e) {
        if (this.page === 0 && e.target.templateInstance.model.item) {
          this.selectedCard = e.target.templateInstance.model.item;
          this.page = 1;
        } else {
          this.page = 0;
        }
      }
    });

  </script>
  </polymer-element>
```

Any advice is appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You should really check out [this article](https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/spa.html)

It will explain many basics and tricks on how to write a single page application. Such as hash-routing, animate-page and ajax-calls.

Comment: Thanks but not necessarily what I was looking for.  I have already read the article before and it doesn't necessarily go into much detail on the core animated pages.